# Incron executes the script two times

Tags: incron

I had a question about incron settings.
It looks i've got an event trigger with **IN_MODIFY,IN_ATTRIB,IN_CLOSE_WRITE** and I'd like to know if two options are triggered then that will execute the script twice? *Because it seems the case today*.

It looks if I add **IN_ONESHOT**, that works correctly, the scirpt being executed once.
That means **IN_ONESHOT** forces to catch only one of these events for executing the script? (*I mean, only one event from this group of event*)

Comment: I believed IN_ONESHOT worked but not. Sorry.
Anyway, the goal is to execute the script one time, whatever the event matched here.
I'm suspecting ATTRIB,IN_CLOSE_WRITE is matched for the same event so the script is executed twice. 
Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem where IN_MODIFY would trigger twice then I added IN_ONESHOT and I receive only one email now.